# OneNote freezing when searching

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote-2016

Recently, my OneNote 2016 started to freeze when I searched in one of my notebooks (high CPU usage, not responsive for several minutes while search was underway). The phenomenon started occuring at the same time at two of my laptops, one was using Windows 10 Pro, the other Windows 10 Enterprise. I tried deleting OneNote cache and resintalled 64 bit version in place of 32 bit but nothing helped. What can be used to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by right-clicking OneNote executable and running compatiblity wizard, which made OneNote execute in Windows 8 mode. That remedied the situation, no more freezes and search happens instantly.